# How to detect changes in "repo" for continuous integration in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, repo

`repo` is a tool from Google that pulls in multiple git repos into one directory.

If I have ten git repos using `repo`, how do I detect changes so that I can kick off CI builds from Jenkins?

For instance, a given manifest (i.e. `default.xml`) may contain

- five git repos that point to `origin/master`
- three git repos that point to `origin/feature1`
- two git repos that point to a `tag`

If these ten repos were in a big monolithic git repo, I would simply create a server side hook to detech changes and start an appropriate Jenkins job.

In a case where the separate ten repos are collected in via `repo`, how do I detect the changes in the appropriate branches and tags?

Comment: did you try [repo plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Repo+Plugin)?

Answer (score 2):

Use the repo Jenkins plugin, found at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Repo+Plugin.

Then use "Gerrit Repo" in the job's "Source Code Management" section, and specify the URL to your repo manifest repository as "Manifest Repository Url".

Comment: Thankyou. Why do no other instructions mention that the Jenkins repo-plugin is referred to as "Gerrit repo" in the UI?